# loop in go helm chart templating

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to loop for a count in a kubernetes helm chart like this:

```
reaction.mongo_url_big: mongodb://{{ for $mongocount := 0; $mongocount < {{ .Values.mongodbReplicantCount }}; $mongocount++ }}{{ .Values.mongodbReleaseName }}-mongodb-replicaset-{{ $mongocount }}:{{ .Values.mongodbPort }}{{ if $mongocount < {{ .Values.mongodbReplicantCount }} - 1 }},{{ end }}{{ end }}/{{ .Values.mongodbName }}?replicaSet={{ .Values.mongodbReplicaSet }}
```

However, go templates seem to be lacking a means of rendering a 'for' loop, [by design](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/ahKwwz4fRFM)

I want it to output something like:

```
 reaction.mongo_url: mongodb://{{ .Values.mongodbReleaseName }}-mongodb-replicaset-0:{{ .Values.mongodbPort }},{{ .Values.mongodbReleaseName }}-mongodb-replicaset-1:{{ .Values.mongodbPort }},{{ .Values.mongodbReleaseName }}-mongodb-replicaset-2:{{ .Values.mongodbPort }}/{{ .Values.mongodbName }}?replicaSet={{ .Values.mongodbReplicaSet }}
```

The line in my helm chart is here:
https://github.com/joshuacox/reactionetes/blob/gymongonasium/reactioncommerce/templates/configmap.yaml#L11

Comment: Your question is about why the developers of a package didn't implement what you want, you'll be better served if you ask the people who made those decisions. If I were you I would try the go mailing list [#go-nuts](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/golang-nuts).

Comment: Related / possible duplicate of [Golang code to repeat an html code n times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46112679/golang-code-to-repeat-an-html-code-n-times/46112802#46112802).

Comment: @icza no clue how to apply your stuff inside a helm template, so I don't think it's duplicate.  However, I think I've found my solution here --> https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/blob/master/stable/aerospike/templates/_helpers.tpl#L23-L25

Comment: This is a valid question, not really opinion-based at all, and it doesn't take much imagination to edit the single  sentence that was deemed unacceptable by the mods into a factual statement... done and voted to re-open.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Notice on the [helm tips and tricks page](https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/blob/master/docs/charts_tips_and_tricks.md) they mention that [sprig](https://godoc.org/github.com/Masterminds/sprig) functions have been added, one of which is until, which can be seen in action [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/blob/master/stable/aerospike/templates/_helpers.tpl#L23-L25)  or in my case:

```
{{- define "mongodb_replicaset_url" -}}
  {{- printf "mongodb://" -}}
  {{- range $mongocount, $e := until (.Values.mongodbReplicaCount|int) -}}
    {{- printf "%s-mongodb-replicaset-%d." $.Values.mongodbReleaseName $mongocount -}}
    {{- printf "%s-mongodb-replicaset:%d" $.Values.mongodbReleaseName ($.Values.mongodbPort|int) -}}
    {{- if lt $mongocount  ( sub ($.Values.mongodbReplicaCount|int) 1 ) -}}
      {{- printf "," -}}
    {{- end -}}
  {{- end -}}
  {{- printf "/%s?replicaSet=%s" $.Values.mongodbName  $.Values.mongodbReplicaSet -}}
{{- end -}}
```

Answer (score 11):

Use range:

```
{{ range .Values }}
   {{ .MongodbReleaseName }}
{{ end }}
```

This will output the .MongodbReleaseName (assuming that's a field) of every item in .Values. The value is assigned to . while within the range so you can simply refer to fields/functions of the individual Values. This is very like a for loop in other templating languages. You can also use it by assigning an index and value.