# How to loop different templates in Helm for Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I want to deploy multiple Deployments of Pods with different images, ports, etc. but with very similar other properties. So I want to declare a single `deployment.yaml` file that looks something like this

```
{{- range .Values.types }}
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
...
{{- end }}
```

Where my `values.yaml` is

```
types:
  - foo
  - bar
  - baz
```

However, this only spins up a single Kubernetes Deployment when I `helm install` because everything is in one template file. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [loop in go helm chart templating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47762628/loop-in-go-helm-chart-templating)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Kubernetes generally uses YAML syntax, and that allows multiple "documents" to be in a single physical file with a `---` delimiter before each one.  Helm in turn generally operates by applying the templating to produce a plain-text file and in effect feeding it to `kubectl apply`.

The upshot of this is that if you start each Kubernetes object description with the `---` start-of-document delimiter, it should work:

```
{{- range .Values.types }}
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
...
{{- end }}
```

Comment: this didn't work for me, the first element of the list disappears